# Switch from double to single column in the same page, for insert long equation

Tags: pdftex, two-column, textwidth

When I using overleaf template [here](https://www.overleaf.com/17289789rdsghfjgmbfm#/65813329/), I changed the codes to `\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}`

I have long equations, so I want to the equation cross the two column. I try change to `\onecolumn`, and then using `multicol` package, but I can't work it out.

Simple codes as following:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
 \usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here
}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor


\maketitle

\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{equation}\label{key}
AcceptAcceptAccept AcceptAcceptAcceptAcceptAcceptAcceptAcceptAccept
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `strip` environment from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} % onecolumn (second format)
\usepackage{cuted} 
\setlength{\stripsep}{0pt}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here
}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\author{First Author \and
        Second Author %etc.
}

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com} % \\
% \emph{Present address:} of F. Author % if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor


\maketitle

\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{strip}
\begin{equation}\label{key}
AcceptAcceptAccept AcceptAcceptAcceptAcceptAcceptAcceptAcceptAccept
\end{equation}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]